# How can I display a 3D model on a form in a Windows Forms project in VB.Net..?

Tags: vb.net, 3d

I recently started working at a company with many custom applications all written in VB, and which I must support/modify. I see an opportunity to creatively display some critical data to my users, and it seems the best way to do so is a form with a 3D model with a stack of cubes, sort of like a bar chart with three axes. I see the FBX editor in the VSIDE, but I'm not sure if that's appropriate for my idea.

Here is what I would like to do:

1. Use a Windows Forms form in a VB.Net project (2012 in this case).
2. Display a 3D model in a frame/box on that form.
3. Have the ability to programmatically modify that model (add/remove cubes).
4. Give users a "hand tool" to rotate model left or right (around the Y axis).
5. GUI editing of the initial model would be helpful, but is not mandatory.

If it were a static model, I could simply plot the lines in a graphics box, but the ability to rotate a "live" model would be outstanding.

I'm new to 3D modeling, so I'm not sure how to approach this. Can anyone suggest a direction for me to go in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WPF`.
Create `WPF` control with 3D and add it to your `Windows form` with [ElementHost control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) .

[Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.110).aspx)

With WPF you can "easily" implement 3D components.
[3-D Graphics Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437(v=vs.110).aspx)

For your particular case I suggest to get known with [3D Charts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489232.aspx) if you already didn't do this.
[Tutorial: Changing to a 3D Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489205.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13842584)

Comment: @techspider, because OP's question doesn't have any specific demands,  essential part of the answer is _Use WPF.
Create WPF control with 3D and add it to your Windows form with ElementHost control_. LInk provided only to support that sentense.

Comment: It may be worth to flag it as too-broad